# How to make a connection between ionic 4 client app and express server?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, ionic4

I'm trying to make a connection between a server and client app using ionic 4, node.js and express. Of course I will need to insert the data into the data base using Mysql, but once I can receive data from client app to server api the rest should not be that difficult. How to make communication between ionic 4 app and express js server?

Most of the tutorial I found online are either focus on the server side or client side. The once touching both are either quit complex for a beginner or using prior versions of technologies. Ionic 3 for exemple or so.
I have been working on this for a couple of days now. Please notice that I'm a beginner with those technology therefore I'm trying just something simple. The purpose here is to bring communication.

What I did so far:
- I create the client project:
- Imported HttpClientModule in the app.module.ts file
- I created  services folder and added a service user using the command:
ionic g service services/user
-I imported HttpCLient in services/user.service.ts file
-I have my home page where I created a simple login form with a button and declare the [(ngModel)]s variables in home.page.ts and the function...
In the other hand, I created the server app in a different folder.
I kept everything simple because the purpose here is to understand and make the connection work. So please while helping try to keep the code simple and remind with the technologies mentioned above as possible.

here something to help you see how the project is organized:

```
//Client app:
//home.page.ts

import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from '../services/user.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {
  login: string;
  pwd: any;
  constructor(private service: UserService) {
  }
  confirmer() {
    const logins = {
      "user": this.login,
      "pwd": this.pwd
    }
    this.service.confirm(logins);
  }

}


//home.page.html
<ion-content>
   Hello
  <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="login"></ion-input>
  <ion-input type="password" [(ngModel)]="pwd"></ion-input>
  <ion-button (click)="confirmer()">Confirmer</ion-button>
</ion-content>

//app.module.ts
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [BrowserModule, HttpClientModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}


//user.service.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {
  user: string;
  pwd: any;
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  confirm(user) {
    return this.httpClient.post('127.0.0.1:300/login', user);
  }


}


//Server side:
//app.js
const express = require('express');
const mysql = require('mysql');

const app = express();
app.listen(3000, function (req, res) {
    console.log('listening...');
});
app.post('/login', function (req, res) {
    console.log("Got a POST request for /login page");
    res.send('Hello POST');
    console.log('Post request...');
 })
```

I'm getting no error at all. These guys seem to work well on their own. There's definitely something that I didn't understand. Please keep the answers as simple possible as I'm not using error handling, storage or whatever. I just want the server to get login and password when user click on "confirmer" button. Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

It was cors issue. Though I adjusted a little the entire code, I had to execute this command on the server side: `npm install --save body-parser cors del express method-override morgan` and added this code: `const bodyParser = require('body-parser'); const logger = require('morgan'); const methodOverride = require('method-override') const cors = require('cors'); app.use(logger('dev')); app.use(bodyParser.json()); app.use(methodOverride()); app.use(cors());` Hope it helps someone in the future –